# Extrinsic curvature of a 2-d plane

Tags: plane-geometry

Imagine there is a 2-d plane as in Fig 1.  I know nobody can live on a 2-d plane, but imagine a Flatlander standing (if that's what Flatlanders do) at position A.  The Flatlander can then move through position B to position C.

If we then give the 2-d plane a little extrinsic curvature, as in Fig 2 (the cross-hatching is meant to indicate the underside of the plane - I apologize for my lack of drawing talent), the Flatlander can still move from A to C, through B, and shouldn't notice any difference from Fig 1.

In Fig 3, the extrinsic curvature is a little more severe, and there are a couple of folds in the 2-d plane (can 2-d planes have folds?).  The Flatlander should still be able to move from point A, through B, to point C.

In Fig 4 though, the "folds" in Fig 3 have been brought together, and the "join" is smooth, so the part of the plane that includes point B has been "pinched-off" from the parts that contain points A and C.

My questions are:

(a) In Fig 3, what does the Flatlander see (assuming Flatlanders can see) as they move from point A to point B, especially when they approach the "fold"?  Presumably they can see point B and point C as though Flatland is still flat - is there any noticeable effect at the "folds"?

(b) in Fig 4 the single "join" is smooth and complete - I assume the Flatlander standing at point A looks along Flatland and sees point C, but cannot see point B (so Flatland is a little shorter than it used to be).  Furthermore, I assume the Flatlander cannot access the segment of Flatland that contains point B.  Are my assumptions here correct, and of not, why not?

[image: 2-d planes]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The answer for the first three is "it depends": If light travels along geodesics of the sheet, the curving (and folding along lines!) is undetectable intrinsically, though if the extrinsic fold is "physically significant" in some way, the fold might be detectable. If light travels along _extrinsic_ geodesics, on the other hand, then as soon as the sheet bends, a chunk of it becomes invisible to inhabitants. Can you easily clarify the question's intent? <> More interestingly, _curved_ folds may be intrinsically detectable, similarly to gravitational lensing.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  No intent really other than curiosity.  I read Flatland many years ago, and Flatterland a couple of years ago, and I found my self wondering about this a little while ago.  From my 3-d (or 4-d I guess) perspective I cant really know what happens on a 2-d plane, but I figured someone in the maths fraternity must have thought about this already - hence the question.

Comment: Actually, a followup if I may.  You indicate that "if the extrinsic fold is "physically significant" in some way, the fold might be detectable" - what would be "physically significant", and how might it be detectable?  How would it manifest on the 2-d plane?

Comment: The kind of thing I had in mind was, maybe you want to assume a fold is reflective like a mirror, so a light ray impinging on a fold "bounces back" (with angle of incidence equal to angle of reflection) instead of "passing through." Those behaviors aren't baked into geometry; in fact, others might take exception to my claim that light "passes through a fold without detecting the fold." My rationale there is, a folded piece of paper is isometric to (has the same intrinsic geometry as) a flat sheet of paper.

Comment: You might be interested in [_Paper surface geometry_](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.06.487) (though it may be less readable than intended). If you don't have access, you're welcome to email and I'll send a link to a PDF.

Comment: Thanks - I've downloaded the paper and I'll take a look.  That might result in more questions...